# Xlrd, xlwt, and xlutils: how do they work together

Tags: python, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

I'm trying to write to an existing xls file and then iterate over rows of the same file until I find a blank.

I understand how to do this via code.

Now my question is, does xlrd "update" it's reference to the sheet? Or do I have to create a new xlrd workbook object via the open workbook function any time I write and then save to it via xlwt's write and save function (to read the new workbook)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xlrd will load your worksheet file into memory **at the time you call the** `open_workbook()` **method**. Any changes made to the worksheet file after you call `open_workbook()` are **not** automatically reflected in the object in memory.

If you take a look at the xlrd source code on Github, in particular the [open_workbook() method of the book.py file](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/9429b4c1cd479830b1ecb08a5e7639244ef8dbcf/xlrd/book.py#L68), you'll see that it loads the contents of the worksheet into memory when the `open_workbook()` method is called. That means, if you call `open_workbook()`, then change the original file, the workbook in memory will not reflect those changes.

This is also why, when you use the xlwt module, you must use the `write()` method - when you modify the contents of the worksheet that is in memory, the changes are not reflected in the original file, until you call `write()`.

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I was looking for. I was pretty sure; didn't know the source code was freely available on github.